# How to SUM filtered columns for each row?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

Google Sheets question.

I have the following sheet which can grow by adding both rows and columns. The first cell of added columns can be either red or blue, randomly:

```
MonthYear | red | blue | blue | red
Jan/2017  | 100 |  200 |   10 |  20
Feb/2017  | 800 |  900 |   50 |  60
```

The result I need should hold the sum for each color:

```
MonthYear | red | blue
Jan/2017  | 120 |  210
Feb/2017  | 860 |  950
```

How can I do this with formulas that update the result automatically when adding new rows/columns in the data sheet?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single formula solution, paste the formula into another sheet:

```
={FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A<>""),{TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:1,Sheet1!B1:1<>""))));MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(OFFSET(Sheet1!B2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A),COUNTA(Sheet1!B1:1))*1),ArrayFormula(--(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:1,Sheet1!B1:1<>""))))=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:1,Sheet1!B1:1<>"")))))}}
```

I've made a [Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q08P4kwVeiwMniDfbSMRanjaaNmC1o1D-wQTpqFQo5Q/edit#gid=592543009) with solution and explanation.

Comment: I am interested in this solution since it doesn't user QUERY. But I am afraid that trying to do it as a single formula over complicates things. Could it be simplified using multiple formulas?

Comment: There are many ways to split it into multiple formulas. You may try calculate any part of the formula in separete place.

Comment: Could you pick this solution apart and explain (or point me to for explanations for) each step? I could use your solution as-is, but I would like to improve my understanding of Google Sheets. Thanks!

Comment: Please, see my sample file.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I set up an example sheet that produces this output:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xex8ptlabXsclb5fJFO5pG78_EQPAJ65xxpNHDhshoU/edit?usp=sharing

The formulae used are:

cell A1: `=ArrayFormula(Sheet1!A:A)`

cell B1: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!B1:1)))`

cell B2: `=SUM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$A,FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$Z,Sheet1!$1:$1=B$1)},"where Col1= date '"&TEXT($A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)),,1))`

The B2 formula is then copied to the rest of the B2:C3 range

Comment: Let me try to process this - I am not very familiar with QUERY.

Comment: Chris, when I add another line in Sheet1, it is not automatically caught in Summary. That is because each result cell has its own formula... I am looking for a solution where there is one single cell with result formula and it doesn't need to be touched when new rows or columns are added.

Comment: agreed, my formula will need to be copied into each new cell.  The excellent arrayformula suggested by @MaxMakhrov will work as you want instead though.  I have added an extra tab to my sheet to demonstrate the difference (the highlighted cells contain the formulae).